# Getting a self-signed certificate error with ProtonBridge and mbsync

Tags: self-signed-certificate, mbsync, isync

I am attempting to setup [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/mbsync.html) with [ProtonBridge](https://protonmail.com/bridge/) and getting the following error:

```
SSL error connecting 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1:1143): self signed certificate
```

I am aware that this is the localhost, as such the certificate that we provide is self-signed. In any other email client, in Thunderbird for instance, it is a matter of confirming a security exception for port `1143` on `127.0.0.1.` as detailed in step 5 [here](https://protonmail.com/bridge/thunderbird). What I quite did not figure out is how to do that in mbsync. Here is my `.msyncrc`:

```
IMAPStore someuser-remote
Host 127.0.0.1
Port 1143
User info@someuser.net
Pass protonbridgepassword
SSLType STARTTLS
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

MaildirStore user-local
Path ~/Mail/
Inbox ~/Mail/INBOX
Subfolders Verbatim
Flatten .

Channel user
Master :user-remote:
Slave :user-local:
Create Both
Expunge Both
Patterns *
SyncState *
```

Tried with option `SystemCertificates no` to no avail as well. Here is the full log:

```
Reading configuration file /home/user/.mbsyncrc
C: 0/1  B: 0/0  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
Channel user
Opening master store user-remote...
Resolving 127.0.0.1... ok
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1:1143)... 
Opening slave store user-local...
SSL error connecting 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1:1143): self signed certificate
C: 1/1  B: 0/0  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746821/getting-a-self-signed-certificate-error-with-protonbridge-and-mbsync#comment107213081_57789973) above by @pusillanimous, I confirm that pointing directly to the cert at the protomail bridge works.

So you simply need to to add the following to your `.mbsyncrc`

```
CertificateFile ~/.config/protonmail/bridge/cert.pem
```

Comment: `CertificateFile "~/Library/Application Support/protonmail/bridge/cert.pem"` on MacOS

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy ProtonBridge's certificate as explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync#Installing) in `Step #1: Get the certificates`. The `openssl` command is somewhat different though, as you need to specify the STARTTLS protocol when connecting to the local server:

```
openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect 127.0.0.1:1143 -showcerts
```

It should give you something along these lines:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = CH, O = Proton Technologies AG, OU = ProtonMail, CN = 127.0.0.1
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CH, O = Proton Technologies AG, OU = ProtonMail, CN = 127.0.0.1
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CH/O=Proton Technologies AG/OU=ProtonMail/CN=127.0.0.1
   i:/C=CH/O=Proton Technologies AG/OU=ProtonMail/CN=127.0.0.1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDizCCAnOgAwIBAgIQBW7/mrcQcB5Iu1POkJ3YNzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBX
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJDSDEfMB0GA1UEChMWUHJvdG9uIFRlY2hub2xvZ2llcyBBRzET

(...)

kNvCZidKp31PdIO9IzQn2cI86f2mo1a+ad5dsd1HU4ZB+B3nMiWbQizaFmD3MrgO
cR/KRJtxKTcXQCBLqIi+t2sDFQ8uozs0xYbGHDrCPgCayZLfAVxGCwP2LANnQKw=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=CH/O=Proton Technologies AG/OU=ProtonMail/CN=127.0.0.1
issuer=/C=CH/O=Proton Technologies AG/OU=ProtonMail/CN=127.0.0.1
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=CH/O=Proton Technologies AG/OU=ProtonMail/CN=127.0.0.1
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms:

(...)
```

Copy the very first block that begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, paste this into a file and save it with a .pem extension. Let's say you name it `protonbridge.pem` subsequently saving it in `/etc/ssl/certs/`, you would need to add this to your `~/mbsyncrc` file:

```
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/protonbridge.pem
```

This should be it, you should now be able to sync. I did not seem to have to copy the root issuer certificate as explained at the end of the step #1 in the link. If you do `mbsync -l channel-name` you will see a list of all mailboxes to sync. You may want to add `Patterns INBOX Sent` if you do not want all and every folder in you Protonmail account to sync, including one called "All Mail"!

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just point the configuration file directly from `~/.config/protonmail/bridge/cert.pem`? Or is there some security implication I'm missing?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot confirm or deny that as I don't remember if I ever tried pointing the configuration file directly as you describe as this was a while ago. It may have not come to my mind doing that. In principle I don't see why it would't work.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that with Thunderbird Version 91.8.1 (64-bit) and Proton Mail Bridge v2.1.1 You can change SMTP security settings to SSL/TLS on both programs and outgoing mail works.